# Why short data type is not called in a constructor

Tags: java

```
public class Overloaded {

    Overloaded(byte i) {
        System.out.println(" con 1 is  called ");
    }

    Overloaded(short j) {

        System.out.println(" con 2 is  called ");
    }

    /*
     * Overloaded(int n) {
     * 
     * 
     * System.out.println(" con 3 is  called ");
     * 
     * 
     * }
     */

    /*
     * Overloaded(long m) {
     * 
     * System.out.println(" con  4 is  called ");
     * 
     * 
     * }
     */

    /*
     * Overloaded(float m) {
     * 
     * System.out.println(" con  5 is  called ");
     * 
     * 
     * }
     */

    public static void main(String[] t) {
        Overloaded o = new Overloaded(127);
    }
}
```

Error :possible lossy conversion from int to short

Comment: please add text that explains your question

Answer (score 2):

The expression `127` is not of type `short` - rather it is of type `int`.

If you want to have an expression of type `short`, use `(short) 127`, as in:

```
Overloaded o = new Overloaded((short)127);
```

Then your example will work.

Comment: Just a word of caution: short values are limited to -32768 to +32767 meaning that e.g. `(short)32768` will result in -32768

Answer (score 2):

All numeric constants are by default of integer type, and when you want to save integer to byte/short field you need to do a [narrowing conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) using cast:

```
(byte)127
(short)127
```

Or in your case:

```
Overloaded o = new Overloaded((byte)127);
```

Or if you want to short:

```
Overloaded o = new Overloaded((short)127);
```

Answer (score -2):

The above code wont produce an error.
It would rather show an output- con 3 is called.
Short type can be called in a constructor.
Typecast it to short

```
Overloaded o = new Overloaded((short)127);
```

Comment: for a better answer, try to explain more. Why it won't produce an error, and why your answer would work.